# ArrayList for java

Tags: java, arrays, collections, filesystems

So, this is my question that I have to answer:

> In the Payroll class, add a method with the header private int
>   computePay(Programmer p). The method should return the programmer’s
>   grade multiplied by the number of hours they worked. For example, if
>   the programmer’s grade is 2, and the total hours they worked is 6, the
>   method should return 12.

But my question for this forum is, how do I get a txt. file which contains `Firstname Secondname,paygrade(Out of 3),hours,hours,hours,hours,hours,hours`

(txt. example;

- Sean Dyke,3,34,54,67,78,34,12
- Fred Flintsone,1,65,78,89,89,34,23
- Scooby Doo,2,54,56,67,87,89,65

)

To make the grade part separate to the hours they work, so I can then use

```
private int computePay(Programmer p){
   return p.grade*p.hours;
}
```

I may have confused myself in this one, or thinking backwards, but any sort of guidelines would help.

Comment: The text file will be the input for your program. You will read the contents of the file to create your objects.

Comment: so do i have to set up a new list and type all in as a normal array would with  Payroll.put "Sean Dyke" + (grade), (hours) or can i use bufferedfilereader to read each line of txt. and input my grade and hours for me?

Comment: Are you asking how to read and parse a comma-separated text file? Did you try searching for that on the web?

Comment: I believe that is what i am asking Andreas. I didn't check up actually, wasnt sure how to word my search. shall try now

Answer (score 0):

I think the grade is after the name so you can split the array and take the values.

```
String[] temp = array1.split(",");

temp[0] gives name
temp[1] gives grade
temp[2...] gives hours worked
```

Answer (score 0):

Well there are 2 ways of storing data in a .txt file:

1. You can put your object into an object stream and simply write that into a textfile.

   ```
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("test.txt");
    ObjectOutputStream oout = new ObjectOutputStream(out);

    // write something in the file
    oout.writeObject(s);

    // close the stream
    oout.close();
   ```
2. Sadly the formating would be really bad and you could not read data on your own. Also that method is really inconsistent. You would need your class to implement `Serializable`. Furthmore, any change in your java code would stop making it possible to read that file.

So I would go for an attampt where you just store the name, followed by those hours. Then, read it line by line:

```
String s = "Sean Dyke,3,34,54,67,78,34,12"
String[] entries = s.split(",");

String name = entries[0];
Integer[] hours = new Integer[entries.length -1];

for(int i = 0; i < hours; i++){
    hours[i] = Integer.parseInt(entries[i + 1]);
}
```

This could would parse one line. Do it for every line in your code txt file and you should be fine.